# Bitbucket Issue POST using using Python and Requests

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a simple POST using python and the Requests module. It appears that when i run the code, it returns the correct status code, but the issue doesn't appear on my public issues page. Since the page is public it doesn't require any logins authentications for posting issues. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Why doesn't it show in bitbucket?

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://bitbucket.org/jokermartini/wingbin/issues"
r = requests.post(url, data={'title': 'New Issue'})
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
print(r.text[:300] + '...')
```

Output:

```
(200, 'OK') 
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
    <head>
        <meta id="bb-bootstrap" data-current-user="{&quot;isKbdShortcutsEnabled&quot;: true, &quot;isSshEnabled&quot;: false, &quot;isAuthenticated&quot;: false}" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />   
        <meta charset="utf-8">   
        <title>  
... 
[Finished in 0.7s]
```

Comment: What is a `r.content` (or `r.json()`)?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Even though you received a 200, you might want to chuck that returned HTML source code on your browser to see what it exactly says. Just to be 100% sure and a good way of debugging any potential problems.

Answer (score 1):

From the [atlassian API docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/issues-resource-296095191.html#issuesResource-POSTanewissue) it seems that you have to be authenticate for POST a new issue:

> Creates a new issue in a repository. This call requires authentication. Private repositories or private issue trackers require the caller to authenticate with an account that has appropriate authorization. The authenticated user is used for the issue's reported_by field.